# How many unique Pokemon in SWSH + DLC + Zarude?

Tags: pokemon-sword-shield, pokemon-isle-of-armor

I'm trying to see if I ran all the unique Pokemon in SWSH + DLC + Zarude what my total Pokemon would be in Pokemon Home.

- Base Pokedex = 400
- Armor = 211 (but there are overlaps with base pokedex)
- Tundra = 210 (also overlaps with base pokedex and armor dex)

I've tried searching online to find the exact number of unique Pokemon in SWSH but it seems to roughly work out as one hundred new unique Pokemon in each DLC, so: 400 + 100 + 100 - but I'm sure that is not exact.

Ideas?

Comment: @Wondercricket I think I'm wrong - I deleted my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on a [Python script](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Wondercricket/SwordShieldCount/main/DexCountScript) I wrote parsing data from [Serebii](https://www.serebii.net/swordshield/galarpokedex.shtml), there are **664** unique Pokémon in Sword and Shield.

1. 80 of the Pokémon do not exist within the various Pokédexes. 68 are  legendaries, ultra beasts, and past generation starters. 12 are Mythicals.
2. 584 of the Pokémon are unique species within the various Pokédexes

Comment: How about without "other"? 584?

Comment: @Mo. Corrected. Based on the script, there are 584 with Pokedex entries